# Java logging through multiple classes

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I would like to log in my application which consist of several classes. I would like to have one .txt log file at the end. Therefore I make one static logger instance and I made a FileHandler for it in one class. Because I would like to have one file, I set the second argument for true in the FileHandler to be able to append the log file during logging.

```
public class MyLogging {
    static Logger logger;
    public Handler fileHandler;
    Formatter plainText;

    public MyLogging() throws IOException{
        //instance the logger
        logger = Logger.getLogger(MyLogging.class.getName());
        //instance the filehandler
        fileHandler = new FileHandler("myLog.txt",true);
        //instance formatter, set formatting, and handler
        plainText = new SimpleFormatter();
        fileHandler.setFormatter(plainText);
        logger.addHandler(fileHandler);

    }
```

After that, I created the other loggers. I know that I have to instance one logger per class.  Therefore I only make the logger (w/o FileHandler) for each class. But all of the loggers referencing for one class (not for the class, where I have created the logger). E.g:

```
public class Test1 {
    static Logger logger;

    public Test1()throws IOException {

        logger = Logger.getLogger(MyLogging.class.getName());
    }
```

Although the logging was performed, I am not sure that this is the right solution. 
Can you give me some advises how to make logging through multiple the classes with the java.util.logging?

Comment: I'm confused. You should have one log file at the end without using only one Logger instance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In MyLogging class, make the constructor `private` instead of `public` , and you need the following methods:

```
private static Logger getLogger(){
    if(logger == null){
        try {
            new MyLogging();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return logger;
}
public static void log(Level level, String msg){
    getLogger().log(level, msg);
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

The `log` method is static, so it can be called from any class using the class name.

So from all your classes, you can log just be invoking log method as below:

```
public class Test1 {
    //static Logger logger; //no need to create an object for logging

    public Test1()throws IOException {

         MyLogging.log(Level.INFO, MyLogging.class.getName()); //call log method using classname
    }
```